# Returning from a function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function in a class definition that returns `undefined`.
Here is the class:

```
class Lexer {
  // constructor and another method here
  make_tokens() {
    var tokens = [];
    // checking character values here
    console.log(tokens); 
    // Outputs [ Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined }, Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined } ] if I enter ++
    return tokens, null; // returns undefined, null
  }
  // make_numbers() goes here
}
```

When I searched for answers, I mainly got returning from asynchronous functions but my function is not asynchronous.

I do not know what the problem is.

(sorry if I didn't structure it well but I am new to StackOverflow and I don't know how to structure a question properly)

Comment: A function returns a **single value** (from discrete math). Yours is trying to return 2(?). Also, read about comma operator; it returns only the last element of the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, why you want to return null with other variable but if so then just return an array consisting of 2 elements.

Here's is the code:

```
class Lexer {
  // constructor and another method here
  make_tokens() {
    var tokens = [];
    // checking character values here
    console.log(tokens); 
    // Outputs [ Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined }, Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined } ] if I enter ++
    return [tokens, null] ; // returns undefined, null
  }
  // make_numbers() goes here
}
```

But it can be the other way. For eg You want to return null if tokens are not present.

```
class Lexer {
  // constructor and another method here
  make_tokens() {
    var tokens = [];
    // checking character values here
    console.log(tokens); 
    // Outputs [ Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined }, Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined } ] if I enter ++
    return tokens | null; // returns undefined, null
  }
  // make_numbers() goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you could return value that way.

```js
class Lexer {
  // constructor and another method here
  make_tokens() {
    var tokens = [];
    // checking character values here
    console.log(tokens); 
    // Outputs [ Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined }, Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined } ] if I enter ++
    return [tokens, null]; // returns undefined, null
  }
  // make_numbers() goes here
}

const lexer = new Lexer();

console.log(lexer.make_tokens());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return multiple values like that.

I think you end up just returning the last value which in this case is `null`.

Why do you need to return `null` aswell?

If you just return `tokens` it will work.

Comment: I need to return null because the function returns an error if there was one so the null represents no error.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `tokens`

```
    class Lexer {
      // constructor and another method here
      make_tokens() {
        var tokens = [];
        // checking character values here
        console.log(tokens); 
        // Outputs [ Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined }, Token { type: 'PLUS', value: undefined } ] if I enter ++
        return tokens; // returns tokens
      }
      // make_numbers() goes here
    }
    
    const lexer = new Lexer();
    
    console.log(lexer.make_tokens());
```